# Alinear dos botones margen inferior izquierdo y derecho

Tags: html, css

Dispongo de un body con X información detallada recogiendo los datos de varios archivos **.php** con conexiones a una BBDD.

Quiero agregar a este fichero .php **dos botones, "Atrás" y "Siguiente".** Deseo que ambos botones estén en el margen inferior izquierdo (Atrás) y margen inferior derecho (Siguiente).

**¿Cómo se debería añadir el estilo para que ambos botones estén al mismo nivel pero cada uno en un lado?**

¿Por cada botón debe existir un formulario o puede ser uno conjunto? He de decir que la funcionalidad de cada botón es distinta.

```
<form action="reservar.php" name="mireserva" id="mireserva" method="POST" style="text-align:center">
    <input type="submit" value="Atrás" name="atras" id="atras">
</form>
<form action="confirmar.php" name="miconfirmar" id="miconfirmar" method="POST" style="text-align:center">
    <input type="submit" value="Confirmar" name="confirmar" id="confirmar">
</form>
```

Comment: Hola, necesariamente tiene que ser una petición mediante un formulario?, Puedes hacer dos link (<a>) para redireccionar la pagina y con css les das estilos a los botones . Me explico ?

Comment: Tiene que ser formulario, al menos, el botón de Confirmar debido  que envía información a otro archivo 
.php. El botón Atrás simplemente es redirigir a un archivo cualquiera.

Comment: Bueno te muestro un ejemplo con lo que tenes y como deberías aplicar los estilos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza las bondades de **flexbox**: Puedes encerrar los dos botones en un div para tener mejor control de ambos (lo he llamado con la clase **botonera**) y a este contenedor aplicarle `display: flex`, luego agregarle un `justify-content: space-between`, que separará ambos elementos el uno del otro según el tamaño establecido para el contenedor. Y listo, es sencillo.

A ese contenedor dentro del form, puedes darle un ancho del 100% para que quede a tope con los bordes del formulario o definir un tamaño según como te convenga.

Otra cosa, no necesitas dos input para tener varios botones dentro del formulario. Ten en cuenta que los input son los que capturan y envían información, pero si sólo necesitas un enlace a otra página, etc, con un `<a></a>` te basta y sobra.

He aquí un ejemplo:

```css
/*Es aquí donde sucede la separación de ambos*/

form {
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 600px;
}

.botonera {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  width: 100%;
}

/* Apariencia de los botones */ 
.boton {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0;
  background: red;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #FFF;
}

.boton-atras {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="reservar.php" name="mireserva" id="mireserva" method="POST" style="text-align:center">
  
  <!-- Contenedor al que se le aplica flexbox -->
  <div class="botonera">
   
    <!-- Botón para ir atrás -->
    <a href="atras.html" id="atras" class="boton boton-atras">Atrás</a>
    
    <!-- Botón para confirmar -->
    <input type="submit" value="Confirmar" name="confirmar" id="confirmar" class="boton">

  </div> <!-- Fin del contenedor -->

</form>
```

Te aconsejo leas un poco sobre lo que es flexbox, para que así puedas llevar tus diseños sin quebraderos de cabeza: [Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

¡Un saludo!

Comment: Gracias.  
¿Y si quiero que los botones estén en un lugar exacto del documento HTML? ¿Valdría con sólo añadir un left-right: xxx px;? Por ejemplo que uno esté en el centro de la página y otro esté en mitad de la página al margen izquierdo

Comment: Puedes hacerlo como en el ejemplo que te dejaron abajo, con `position: absolute` y justamente aplicando el left-right. Pero las posiciones pueden verse afectadas si el contenedor cambia de tamaño o se agregan elementos. En cuanto a posicionamientos sencillos siempre recomiendo flexbox, este te permite posicionar diferentes elementos rápidamente aplicando `justify-content` y/o `align-items` al contenedor y `align-self` al elemento que quieres posicionar dentro de dicho contenedor. 

Échale un ojo al link que te dejé ahí abajo, junto con algún tutorial y verás lo sencillo que es.

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te dejo como deberían estar los estilos para que tengas los dos botones en cada lado , en la parte inferior.

La clave esta en la propiedad **position: absolute** y en darle a cada botón la posición.

Espero que sea de ayuda.

```css
#atras,
#confirmar {
  position: absolute;
  background: skyblue;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#atras:hover,
#confirmar:hover {
  background: rgba(135, 206, 235, 0.8);
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#confirmar {
  right: 10px;
}

#atras {
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form action="reservar.php" name="mireserva" id="mireserva" method="POST" style="text-align:center">
    <input type="submit" value="Atrás" name="atras" id="atras">
</form>
<form action="confirmar.php" name="miconfirmar" id="miconfirmar" method="POST" style="text-align:center">
    <input type="submit" value="Confirmar" name="confirmar" id="confirmar">
</form>
```

Comment: ¿Y si quiero que los botones estén en un lugar exacto del documento HTML? ¿Valdría con sólo añadir un left-right: xxx px;? Por ejemplo que uno esté en el centro de la página y otro esté en mitad de la página al margen izquierdo

Comment: Hola, si es correcto. Hoy en dia hay varias formas de posicionar elementos, esta flexbox como te comentaron ( tienes que agregarles prefixer para la compatibilidad de navegadores ) , la nueva tendencia "CSS Grid layout", flotar elementos con float. A veces te puede dar un dolor de cabeza los posicionamientos. En base a lo que yo te indique te dejo un link para que veas un poco http://librosweb.es/libro/css/capitulo_5/posicionamiento_absoluto.html